# Meaning of AVFoundation error codes -11800/-16364

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avkit

It's very hard to know from AVFoundation error codes what is the exact error. For instance, I see the following message and don't know what error code means?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-11800/-16364` is the error `-16364` wrapped in the `AVFoundation` error `-11800` (`AVErrorUnknown`).

As far as I can tell `-16364` is undocumented, but I associate it with timestamp misuses, like trying to encode `CMSampleBuffer`s with non strictly monotonic increasing timestamps (repeating or decreasing).
I guess that means the error originates in `CoreMedia` or `VideoToolbox` or something similar.

Comment: Saved me a week! Also, in addition to this answer: Try to debug this by appending timestamps to array, but NOT by comparing latest two. You can track duplication in the last of 10 or 20, because AVAssetWriter (or encoder) has its own internal queue, so you can append  some frames after some illegal sequence of timestamps, and get .failure status a bit later, what actually confuses.